# Dato fantasma en ciclo while

Tags: python, while

estoy haciendo un pequeño programa, es muy simple, es solo una secuencia de if.

El programa me funciona bien, el único inconveniente es que me imprime uno de mas.
Se ponen los datos, entra a un ciclo y se repite x veces, segun la variable  `num_cambio`, pero sin importar el numero siempre me imprime 1 de mas, este es eñ codigo:

```
import random
contador = 0
cuenta = str(input())
num_cambio = int(input())
        
if num_cambio > 3:
    print("Fuera de rango")

elif num_cambio < 0:
    print("Fuera de rango")

else:
    while contador != num_cambio:
        if cuenta == "v":
            cuenta = random.choice(["v", "r"])
            print(cuenta)

            
        if cuenta == "a":
            cuenta = random.choice(["v", "a"])
            print(cuenta)

            
        if cuenta == "r":
            cuenta = random.choice(["r", "a"])
            print(cuenta)
        
        else:
            None
        
        contador += 1
```

una pequeña solución es iniciar la variable `contador` a 1, pero eso evita que pueda utilizar 1 como numero, ¿Alguna idea de lo que este pasando?

Esto pasa con cualquieras de las variables, si coloco que quiero 3 ciclos me imprime 4.

Planteamiento del problema(Solo para el contexto, no es necesario de leer)
La primer línea de entrada contendrá una letra R, A o V (rojo, azul o verde) representando el color de la cuenta inicial. La segunda línea contendrá un número representando el número de cambios de color que tendrá el collar.

Comment: la asignación  etc =: str(input()) es redundante, la función input ya devuelve una cadena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no está en la cuenta; está en que en un mismo ciclo imprimes dos veces.

Si cuenta = 'v', El primer `if`

```
   if cuenta == "v":
        cuenta = random.choice(["v", "r"])
        print(cuenta)
```

imprime la cuenta y cambia `cuenta` a `r`, y en el tercer `if`, vuelves a comparar `cuenta` y vuelves a imprimir.

```
    if cuenta == "r":
        cuenta = random.choice(["r", "a"])
        print(cuenta)
```

**Solución**

Usa if-elif para no repetir las comparaciones

```
    if cuenta == "v":
        cuenta = random.choice(["v", "r"])
        print(cuenta)
    elif cuenta == "a":
        cuenta = random.choice(["v", "a"])
        print(cuenta)
    elif cuenta == "r":
        cuenta = random.choice(["r", "a"])
        print(cuenta)
```

Con eso evitaras dos hits en la misma pasada.

Comment: ¡Gracias!, Fue de mucha ayuda